# Implementing 'direction="vertical"' in a Vue 3 app for the img-comparison-slider library

Tags: javascript, html, image, vuejs3

In the docs for the library [here](https://img-comparison-slider.sneas.io/examples.html#vertical) it mentions an ability to use the vertical version, which I would very much like to use. I have a completely functional default version in horizontal mode running, but I cannot get it to change any of the available settings no matter if it is the vertical or anything else. Is there something that I'm forgetting to import??

**Component Code**

```
<img-comparison-slider direction="vertical" style="margin-bottom: 3vh; ">
  <img :src="beforeAlignedImageAsset" alt="beforeAlignedImageAsset" slot="first" style="height: auto; max-height: 65vh;">
  <img :src="afterAlignedImageAsset" alt="afterAlignedImageAsset" slot="second" style="height: auto; max-height: 65vh;">
</img-comparison-slider>
```

**Script Import**

```
import { ImgComparisonSlider } from '@img-comparison-slider/vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: '###',
  components: {
    ImgComparisonSlider
  },
```

Element simply does not change to reflect any of the supposed settings available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but there must be bug in the library. When you declare direction as initial value this not change. If we set onMounted cycle, its works.

My working example:

```js
<template>
  <ImgComparisonSlider
    :direction="direction"
    tabindex="0"
    style="margin-bottom: 3vh; "
  >
    <img
      slot="first"
      style="width: 100%"
      src="https://img-comparison-slider.sneas.io/demo/images/before.webp"
    />
    <img
      slot="second"
      style="width: 100%"
      src="https://img-comparison-slider.sneas.io/demo/images/after.webp"
    />
  </ImgComparisonSlider>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ImgComparisonSlider } from '@img-comparison-slider/vue';
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
const direction = ref('');
onMounted(() => {
  direction.value = 'vertical';
});
</script>
```